# webkit-text-stroke works differently on two pages

Tags: css, webkit, font-awesome

I'm using `-webkit-text-stroke:2px white;` on two different pages for the same FontAwesome character. But the results differ and I can't figure out why.
Here are the related CSS for both-

page1-

```
#page_title_container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

#page_title_container .fa-angle-up {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1);
  transform: scale(1.5, 1);
  margin-left: -2px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
}
```

page2-

```
.section-title-container{
}

.section-title-container .fa-angle-up {
  color: #fff;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1);
  transform: scale(1.5, 1);
  margin-left: -2px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}
```

(These are the closest effecting styles. Will upload more if needed.)

And here are the results-

page1-
[image]

page2-
[image]

Seems like in the first case, only the edges are getting bolder by 2px. The second case is the desired result.

Can anyone explain why it is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Can you inpsect the element with dev tools and see what styles are being applied?

Comment: Okay. I checked. The same styles are applied for both. But when I change the webkit-stroke size, the first one only changes the border size of the character with centre transparent, the second one actually changes the stroke size as desired.

Comment: Is anything overriding it?

Comment: Nope. The first two transform statements are overridden by the third one in both cases. And the second thing applying to this is webkit-stroke which is not overridden.